# Laravel collection order similar to DB FIELD

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-collection

I have a query with following order

`$query->orderByRaw("FIELD(type, 'red', 'green', 'aqua') ASC");`

This will order items not alphabetically, but specifically by the value.

Is there is a way to do same thing in `Laravel` collection?

Like:

```
$collection = collect(`Items from DB`);

$final = $collection->sortBy(function($item){
    return $item->color == 'red'
});
```

Comment: You can not `orderByRaw` on collection you can do within query.

Comment: @Rits I know that I can't use `orderByRaw` on collection, I'm looking to an solution to use collection `sortBy` function with same logic like `orderByRaw`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
$collection = collect(`Items from DB`);

$final = $collection->sortBy(function($model){
    return array_search($model->color, ['red', 'green', 'aqua']);
});
```

[array_search](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php) return item position (key), so if model color is `red` the key is 0 and so on. and this will order it.

If there is other solutions (maybe faster) please post them, thank you.

Comment: Instead of `array_search`, you can create array `['red' => 1, 'green' => 2]` and then return `$array[$model->color]`. This would be faster than executing `array_search` each time.